# Objective -C XCTests: how to swipe all the way up in a table cells

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, xcode-ui-testing

I have a table with 7 cells (could increase in future). Only 4 cells are visible and are hittable from UI on screen1. I want to tap 7th cell go to screen2 and I am successfully able to scroll down (checking if cell is hittable and scrolling one cell at a time) and tap 7th cell but once I come back to screen1,  I want to swipe all the to top at once (not scrolling one cell at a time). I tried using "swipeup" but when doing so it is tapping on the cell and I am navigated to screen2 (and test fails) which I don't want to happen. 
How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.
code for scroll down:

```
 int elementIndex = 0;
NSArray *cells = tableView.cells.allElementsBoundByIndex;

for(XCUIElement *cell in cells){
NSString *name = transactionCell.staticTexts[@"Name"].label;
            if (!cell.hittable) {
                [Testfunc scrollDown:tableView withApp:app index:elementIndex-1];

            }
        [cell tap];
        elementIndex++;
        //do stuff if this is the correct cell else go to next cell
        }

+ (void) scrollDown:(XCUIElement*)tableView withApp:(XCUIApplication*)app index:(int)elemntIndex {
    XCUIElementQuery* tableCells = tableView.cells;
    int tableCount = (int)tableCells.count;
    if(index > 0 && elemntIndex < tableCells.count-1){
        XCUIElement* startElement = [tableCells elementBoundByIndex:elemntIndex];
        XCUIElement* endElement = [tableCells elementBoundByIndex:elemntIndex-1];
        [startElement pressForDuration:0.1 thenDragToElement:endElement];

    }
}
```

I tried scroll all the way up by doing:

```
XCUIElement *elementSwipe = transactionCell.staticTexts[name];
[elementSwipe swipeUp];
```

But then it taps on the cell before scrolling up and I am navigated to screen2. Then test fails.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to tap on your status bar like:
`XCUIApplication().coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.02)).tap()`

It would scroll all the way to top.

Answer (score 3):

Tap on the status bar, that should scroll you to the top.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.statusBars.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
```